# Difference Between Orientation Sensor and Accelerometer Sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to know about the values of X,Y and Z axis for any position/movement of device so I can use these values for my further work. As I searched there are two methods, Orientation Sensor(gives value in degree,as azimuth,pitch and roll) and Accelerometer(gives values between 1 to 10 for x,y and z).

As per my understanding both are same for my requirement. I can't find difference between them. Please can any one clear me about them in detail w.r.t my aim. which sensor should I use?

Answer (score 5):

There are differences between both:

Accelerometer detects acceleration in space.  The reason why it will always detect an acceleration of 9.8m/s^2 downwards is because gravity is equivalent to acceleration in space.

Orientation detects if your device's axis are rotated from the real-world; it detects tilts and and degrees from the magnetic North. Please note that this sensor is deprecated and Google recommends you use the accelerometer and magnetometer to calculate orientation.

Comment: Do you know if when you query the orientation, it uses internally the magnetometer and acceleration?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the accelerometer to detect movement. So you should use this one, since your aim is to know this movement.

The orientation sensor gives information about its position compared to a reference plane. So you could use this to see of the device is tilted, upside down or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometer shows fixed value when we tilt the phone in different position. So, it is difficult to depend this sensor to check the speed/movement-spikes. Because, same x,y,z reading for phone tilt and phone movement. How can we differentiate the readings?